# generating a scatter plot using two different dataset in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two datasets. Both have different numbers of observations. Is it possible to generate a scatter plot between features from different datasets?

For example, I want to generate a scatter plot between the submission_day column of dataset 1 and the score column of dataset 2.

I am not sure how to do that using python packages.

For example consider the following two datasets:

```
     id_student submission_day 
         23hv          100
         24hv           99
         45hv           10
         56hv           16
         53hv           34


     id_student score
         23hv      59
         25gf      20
         24hv      56
         45hv      76
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Because if different size of data first step is create DataFrame - join both df together.

Comment: they have a primary key  Id_student

Comment: hmmm, so merge  by left join? But without data hard to know...

Comment: here is the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for one `DataFrame` and then [`DataFrame.plot.scatter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='id_student')
print (df)
  id_student  submission_day  score
0       23hv             100     59
1       24hv              99     56
2       45hv              10     76

df.plot.scatter(x='submission_day', y='score')
```